# SCSS not working within a REACT app specifically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I'm pretty sure its my folders filepath for my compile Sass script, but I've been at this one a few hours now, so I'm hoping you can help... (maybe there's a setup setting IDK about?...

**Two similar projects - 1 Vanilla, 1 React.** 
**1.** On both I have **node**, **NPM** and **node-sass** installed; via: *npm i --save-dev node-sass*
**2.** I've got livesass compiler going. On vanilla it works as expected. On the React project live-sass-compiler keeps on crashing (it is working long enough for me to test it though) and when i run in the terminal: **npm run compile:sass** the terminal turns into a node, never compiles, and also seems to get stuck in this state.

Please help!

**NOW FOR THE DIFFERENCES: 

==========Filepaths==========** 
(Filepath is indicated by "./", multiple files indicated by array syntax.

---

**Vanilla (root):**

**index.html** (stylesheet href="./STYLES/SCSS/index.css")
**index.js**
**./STYLES/** [**index.css**, **index.css.map**, **index.scss**]
**package.json** (script: "compile:sass": "node-sass STYLES/SCSS/index.scss STYLES/output.css -w")

Works great!

---

**REACT (root):**

**./public/index.html** (stylesheet href="../src/STYLES/CSS/index.css")
**./src/index.js**
**.src/STYLES/** [**index.scss**, (desired css output)]
**package.json** (script: "compile:sass": "node-sass src/STYLES/index.scss src/STYLES/CSS/index.css -w")

---

in both of them, inside the node-modules folder, I have installed:  
**"devDependencies": {"node-sass": "^7.0.1"}**

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, React output settings are completely unchanged. I havn't manually configured any webpack settings different than what comes standard from create-react-app. (
The build folder has "index.html", and "./static/main.###.css"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hey, I figured it out!** 
 - I got rid of **live-sass-compiler** (it's depreciated). 
 - I also removed the "*script: "compile:sass": "node-s..."*" as it's no longer required. Compilation will happen natively every time you save the file.

### **TO USE WITH REACT:**

**Terminal:**

***npm install -D sass 

sass —watch scss:css***

**1.** add an **.env** file to the root. Inside type: “SASS_PATH=src/STYLES/SCSS”

(this allowed relative paths to be ignored on previous versions. I haven't gotten this to work but everything else seems to work. It may be depreciated... IDK.)

**2.** include the filepath import to the JS page you’d like the CSS to live under:

(example (for APP-WIDE Changes): **index.js:** import './STYLES/index.scss’ //imports to the app component

**3.** to import another file from index.scss:
Within the **index.scss** file:
@use './SCSS/_unorganized.scss'; // (**"@import" will soon be depreciated, instead use @use)**

Hope this saves someone else some time!